# Shell script: How to partition a file into columns?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file that looks like:

```
t1   ATGCGTCCGTAGCAG
t2   ATGCCTAGCTAGGCT
```

i.e. a name followed be a (DNA) sequence. I would like to partition the sequence. For example, the above sequence have a length of 15 and I'd like to partition it into 3 parts of length 5. I want to have three new files such that:

## file1

```
t1   ATGCG
t2   ATGCC
```

## file2

```
t1   TCCGT
t2   TAGCT
```

## file3

```
t1   AGCAG
t2   AGGCT
```

I am trying to write a shell script to accomplish this. One way would be to write a for-loop to get the Nth line of the file using `sed '$Nq;d'`, and then cutting it by `cut -c` command and save it into a variable. Then, using `cut, head, tail` commands and one more variable I will achieve it. But, I am wondering if there is a better way (neatness and speed) to do this.

PS: The actual files will contain 1-10 thousands of lines and each sequence has length of 10-50k length and I will partition the sequences into sequences of length 1-2k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses substring notation (i.e. string:start:length) to extract the requested output:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo ${line:0:10} >> file1
    echo ${line:0:5}  ${line:10:5} >> file2
    echo ${line:0:5}  ${line:15:5} >> file3
done < "$1"
```

Save it into myscript.sh and run it with: `./myscript.sh <input-file>`

Comment: Good catch on the secondary test of `$line` following the read to protect against a file without a `newline` following the last line of data (a non-POSIX line ending).

Answer (score 1):

One-liner solution, uses a single loop:

```
for i in $(seq 3); do cut -c1-5,$((i * 5 + 1))-$(((i + 1) * 5)) < source.txt > file$i.txt ; done
```

Adjust the calculation for your own widths. You really don't need to do this line-by-line, it would be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

awk can help

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=3;i++)print $1" "substr($2,5*(i-1)+1,5) >> "file"i".txt"}' inputfilename
```

expanding awk

```
awk '{
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
          print $1" "substr($2,5*(i-1)+1,5) >> "file"i".txt"
     }' inputfilename
```